# How to extract parts from a string

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I have an string called **PATTERN**:

```
PATTERN <- "MODEL_Name.model-OUTCOME_any.outcome-IMP_number"
```

and I would like to parse the string using a pattern matching function, like `grep`, `sub`, ... to obtain a string variable **MODEL** equal to *"Name.model"*, a string variable **OUTCOME** equal to *"any.outcome"* and an integer variable **IMP** equal to *number*.

If **MODEL**, **OUTCOME** and **IMP** were all  integers, I could get the values using function `sub`:

```
PATTERN <- "MODEL_002-OUTCOME_007-IMP_001"
pattern_build <- "MODEL_([0-9]+)-OUTCOME_([0-9]+)-IMP_([0-9]+)"

MODEL <- as.integer(sub(pattern_build, "\\1", PATTERN))
OUTCOME <- as.integer(sub(pattern_build, "\\2", PATTERN))
IMP <- as.integer(sub(pattern_build, "\\3", PATTERN))
```

Do you have any idea of how to match the string contained in variable **PATTERN**?

Possible tricky patterns are:

```
PATTERN <- "MODEL_PS2-OUTCOME_stroke_i-IMP_001"
PATTERN <- "MODEL_linear-model-OUTCOME_stroke_i-IMP_001"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a pattern with capturing groups matching any chars, as few as possible between known delimiting substrings:

```
MODEL_(.*?)-OUTCOME_(.*?)-IMP_(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEuPU3/1). Note that the last `.*` is greedy since you get all the rest of the string into this capture.

You may precise this pattern to only allow matching expected characters (say, to match digits into the last capturing group, use `([0-9]+)` rather than `(.*)`.

Use it with, say, `str_match` from *stringr*:

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- "MODEL_Name.model-OUTCOME_any.outcome-IMP_number"
> res <- str_match(x, "MODEL_(.*?)-OUTCOME_(.*?)-IMP_(.*)")
> res[,2]
[1] "Name.model"
> res[,3]
[1] "any.outcome"
> res[,4]
[1] "number"
>
```

A base R solution using the same regex will involve a `regmatches` / `regexec`:

```
> res <- regmatches(x, regexec("MODEL_(.*?)-OUTCOME_(.*?)-IMP_(.*)", x))[[1]]
> res[2]
[1] "Name.model"
> res[3]
[1] "any.outcome"
> res[4]
[1] "number"
>
```

Comment: That's a nice and clean approach. Thank you! It remains to check whether if results are going to be stored always in position 2,3 and 4.

Comment: Yes, always in 2, 3, and 4 since they are in *capturing group* buffers (the first item contains the *whole* match value). I also added a base R solution for the suggested regex.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A solution which is also able to deal with the 'tricky' patterns:

```
PATTERN <- "MODEL_linear-model-OUTCOME_stroke_i-IMP_001"

lst <- strsplit(PATTERN, '([A-Z]+_)')[[1]][2:4]
lst <- sub('-$','',lst)
```

which gives:

```
> lst
[1] "linear-model" "stroke_i"     "001"
```

---

And if you want that in a dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame.list(lst)
names(df) <- c('MODEL','OUTCOME','IMP')
```

which gives:

```
> df
         MODEL  OUTCOME IMP
1 linear-model stroke_i 001
```

Comment: Hi Jaap, I need to match string instead of integers. For integers I suggested a possible approach

Comment: @marc1s updated with a solution for the tricky patterns as well

Answer (score 3):

A minimal-regex approach,

```
sapply(strsplit(PATTERN, '-'), function(i) sub('(.*?_){1}', '', i))
#     [,1]      
#[1,] "PS2"     
#[2,] "stroke_i"
#[3,] "001"
```

Comment: I thing this approach fails when pattern contains the symbol "\_". For example, `PATTERN=MODEL_PS2-OUTCOME_stroke_i-IMP_001`

Comment: Indeed. You should always include peculiar/corner-case cases in your example. Let me revise